# VPN can access network drives by IP but not by computer name

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I have a VPN set up on my laptop. When I take it out of the office I can't access mapped network drives. I noticed that all my network drives went something like `\\THE-FILE-SERVER\Data`, but when I changed the computer name with actual local IP address so it became like this `\\192.168.1.5\Data` then I can access those shared drives via VPN.

Why is that? Is there a way to make it so my netowrk drives that are mapped using file server's computer name instead of IP work both in the office and remotely via VPN? At the moment I have two same shared drives but one uses computer name (in the office it works) and one uses LAN IP(remotely on VPN works).

I have "Use remote network default gateway" checked under TCP\IP 4 and 6 advanced settings.

Comment: If you specify the work domain along with the host name (ie: `\\the-file-server.YourCompanyDomain.local\Data`), does it work then?

Comment: I would look at your DNS settings when you're on the VPN compared to when you're at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this could be a DNS issue in resolving the FQDN name of the shared path. Try removing the network shared drive and adding it back. Open your command prompt with Run as Administrator mode and use :

```
net use * /delete
```

Now, add the map the network shared location in the Windows Explorer > Tools > Map Network Drive and enter the required information. Now try to access the information.

Hope this helps.